# Python Splitting a Generator Yield into Two Parts

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I have access to a generator that yields two values:

```
def get_document_values():
    docs = query_database()  # returns a cursor to database documents
    for doc in docs:
        # doc is a dictionary with ,say, {'x': 1, 'y': 99}
        yield doc['x'], doc['y']
```

I have another function, `process_x`, that I cannot change that can take a generator in as input that processes all of the `x` for all documents (if a tuple is yielded then it just processes the first element of the tuple and ignores the other elements):

```
X = process_x(get_document_values())  # This processes x but ignores y
```

However, I need to store all of the `y` values from the generator as well. My only solution is to execute `get_document_values` twice:

```
Y = [y for x,y in get_document_values()]  #Throw away x
X = process_x(get_document_values())      #Throw away y
```

This technically works but when there are many documents to process, it is possible that a new document will get inserted into the database and the lengths of `X` and `Y` will be different. There needs to be a one-to-one mapping between `X` and `Y` and I'd like to only have to call `get_document_values` once instead of twice.

I've considered something like:

```
Y = []

def process_y(doc_generator):
    global Y
    for x,y in doc_generator:
        Y.append(y)
        yield x

X = process_x(process_y(get_document_values()))
```

But:

1. This doesn't feel pythonic
2. `Y` needs to be declared as a global variable

I am hoping that there is a cleaner, more pythonic way to do this.

**Update**

In reality, `get_document_values` will return values of `x` that are too large to be collectively stored into memory and `process_x` is actually reducing that memory requirement. So, it is not possible to cache all of `x`. Caching all of `y` is fine though.

Answer (score 2):

You are caching all the values into a list already when calling:

```
all_values = [(x,y) for x,y in get_document_values()] #or list(get_document_values())
```

You can get an iterator to `y` values with:

```
Y = map(itemgetter(1), all_values)
```

And for `x` simple use:

```
X = process_x(map(itemgetter(0), all_values))
```

The other option is to separate the generator, for example:

```
def get_document_values(getter):
    docs = query_database()  # returns a cursor to database documents
    for doc in docs:
        # doc is a dictionary with ,say, {'x': 1, 'y': 99}
        yield getter(doc)

from operator import itemgetter
X = process_x(get_document_values(itemgetter("x")))
Y = list(get_document_values(itemgetter("y")))
```

This way you will have to do the query twice, if you find a way of do the query once and duplicate the cursor, then you can abstract it also:

```
def get_document_values(cursor, getter):
    for doc in cursor:
        # doc is a dictionary with ,say, {'x': 1, 'y': 99}
        yield getter(doc)
```

Comment: Nice and simple. But maybe not use `all` as a variable name.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Right, missing `(...)`. Or just `all_values = list(get_document_values())`

Comment: In reality, `get_document_values` will return values of `x` that are too large to be stored into memory and `process_x` is actually reducing that memory requirement. So, it is not possible to cache all of `x`. Caching all of `y` is fine though. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the solution?

Comment: @slaw, then the better option is to separate the generator, Ill update the answer

Answer (score 1):

No need to save the data:

```
def process_entry(x, y):
    process_x((x,))
    return y

ys = itertools.starmap(process_entry, your_generator)
```

Just remember that **only** when you get a `y` value, its corresponding `x` value is processed.

If you beed both, return both as a tuple:

```
def process_entry(x, y):
    return next(process_x((x,))), y
```

Comment: Where is the result of `process_x` stored? Notice that in my question the result of processing all `x` is stored in `X`.

Comment: I noticed an issue. `process_x` takes a generator that yields values of `x` as input and not `x` directly. So, I don't think this works but maybe I misunderstand the way that `starmap` works.

Comment: starmap just unpacks arguments to a function.

Comment: + and proceeds as `map` obviously :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [itertools.tee](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) to make two iterators from one, then use one iterator for `process_x` and second for the other purpose

Comment: It should be noted that unless the two iterators are consumed interleavingly (which in OP's example there are not) then `tee` will internally cache all the values in a list/queue or similar, so no real benefit over storing them in a list up-front.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not pythonic, but you can cheat a little bit if it is permissible to change the main generator a little and make use of its function attribute:

```
from random import randrange
def get_vals():
        # mock creation of a x/y dict list
        docs =[{k: k+str(randrange(50)) for k in ('x','y')} for _ in range(10)]
        # create a function list attribute
        get_vals.y = []
        for doc in docs:
            # store the y value into the attribute
            get_vals.y.append(doc['y'])
            yield doc['x'], doc['y']  
            # if doc['y'] is purely for storage, you  might opt to not yield it at all.
```

---

Test it out:

```
# mock the consuming of generator for process_x            
for i in get_vals():
    print(i)    
# ('x13', 'y9'), ('x15', 'y40'), ('x41', 'y49')...

# access the ys stored in get_val function attribute after consumption
print(get_vals.y)
# ['y9', 'y40', 'y49', ...]

# instantiate the generator a second time a la process_x...
for i in get_vals():
    print(i)
# ('x18', 'y0'), ('x6', 'y35'), ('x24', 'y45')...

# access the cached y again
print(get_vals.y)
# ['y0', 'y35', 'y45', ...]
```

1. This basically caches your y values as the generator outputs its x for each call.
2. And it eliminates your `global` keyword
3. And you can be sure the x/y mapping is accurate.

Some might consider this a hack, but I'd like to think of this as a feature since everything in Python is an object it allows you to get away with this...